# Error when On Error Resume Next

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-errors

I can't build exe :

> ### 1> ------ Assembly started: project: B, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
>
> B.vb (38.9): error BC36595: The method can not simultaneously contain
>   an "On Error Resume Next" statement and define a variable that is used
>   in the lambda expression or query expression.
>
> Assembling: successful: 0, with errors: 1, no change: 0, skipped: 0

From line 37 to 48:

```
Sub Read(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    On Error Resume Next
    If TCP.GetStream.DataAvailable And TCP.GetStream.CanRead Then
        Dim tt As New Thread(AddressOf Data) : tt.IsBackground = True : tt.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) : tt.Start(DirectCast(bf.Deserialize(TCP.GetStream), Byte()))
        TCP.GetStream.Flush() : TCP.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Read, Nothing)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        GoTo r
    End If 
r:
    Disconnect()
End Sub
```

I'm trying to use try\catch, but don't know, is that correct? :

```
Sub Read(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        If TCP.GetStream.DataAvailable And TCP.GetStream.CanRead Then
            Dim tt As New Thread(AddressOf Data) : tt.IsBackground = True : tt.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) : tt.Start(DirectCast(bf.Deserialize(TCP.GetStream), Byte()))
            TCP.GetStream.Flush() : TCP.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Read, Nothing)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch
        GoTo r
    Finally
    End Try
r:
    Disconnect()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is VB.NET not C#

Comment: By the way. On Error Resume Next should be discarded as soon as possible. Use the provided NET [Structured exception handling](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315965/how-to-use-structured-exception-handling-in-visual-basic-.net-or-in-visual-basic-2005)  (Try/Catch/Finally)

Comment: I don't get that so many keeps mistaking VB.NET for C#...

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the error message means what it says, that you can't use `On Error Resume Next` and also define a variable that is used in the lambda expression or query expression? I suggest you take the advice given by @Steve and use a Try/Catch/Finally block instead of `On Error`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i'll try try\catch and edited the question

Comment: I presume that you are modifying some existing code.  Do you know what errors get skipped by the `On Error Resume Next`?  When those errors occur, do you know which statements will still execute and which ones will not?  Is that behavior correct (or at least, is it behavior you need to preserve), or should you instead bail out on error?  You need to answer these questions before you can make changes, because the answers determine the exact changes you will need to make.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763077.aspx) on that error message tells you how to fix it:

> ### To correct this error
>
> 1. Replace the exception handling code that uses the **On Error Goto** statement with a **Try...Catch** statement.

The **Try ... Catch** will have the following sections:

- `Try` - what should be executed
- `Catch` - What should be executed if an exception is thrown within the `Try`
- `Finally` - What should be executed *whether there is an exception or not*.

> I'm trying to use try\catch, but don't know, is that correct?

It *might* work, but the `Exit Sub` and `Goto` are unnecessary and confuse things.  I would instead try:

```
Sub Read(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        If TCP.GetStream.DataAvailable And TCP.GetStream.CanRead Then
            Dim tt As New Thread(AddressOf Data) : tt.IsBackground = True : tt.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) : tt.Start(DirectCast(bf.Deserialize(TCP.GetStream), Byte()))
            TCP.GetStream.Flush() : TCP.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Read, Nothing)
        End If
    Catch
        Disconnect()
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

But it seems odd to only call `Disconnect()` if there is an exception.  Should the connection remain open otherwise?  How does the caller know if `Disconnect` has been called or not?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but i don't know how to logic it correct :\